# WordPress вывод закрепленых статей (прилепить) PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Доброй утро!

Надеюсь может кто-то знает - как вывести в Wordpress прилепленые статьи

Как обычные вывести я знаю - но не могу найти негде как прилепленые.

Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php $my_posts = get_posts('numberposts=3&category=home-post-2');
 foreach ($my_posts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сведения о прилепленных постах находятся в опции, которую надо сначала прочитать. Код такой:

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$my_posts = get_posts('post__in=' . $sticky);
foreach ($my_posts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое - стало понятнее